# Converging to infinity or diverging to infinity?

Tags: calculus

When I see my calculus textbook it said a sequence diverges to infinity while wikipedia says a sequence converges to infinity with the same concept. What is the difference between two terms? And why do we use both of them?

Comment: I have not encountered the phrase "convergent to infinity"....I'd have said that a convergent sequence had to converge to a number.  I suppose it's possible that some want to distinguish between divergent sequences for which the terms become arbitrarily large, as in $\{n\}$ and those for which the terms  oscillate, as in $\{(-1)^n\}$.  But what would one then say about something like $\{(-n)^n\}$?

Comment: Which Wikipedia article says "converges to infinity"? The relevant section at  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_of_a_sequence#Infinite_limits only says "tend[s] to infinity."

Answer (score 2):

"*Converges to infinity*" is really uncommon and should be avoided, we usually say that

- $a_n \to L \in \mathbb{R}$ the sequence **converges** (e.g. $a_n=1/n$)
- $a_n \to \pm \infty$ the sequence **diverges** (e.g. $a_n=n$)
- otherwise the sequence has not limit or that the **limit doesn't exist** (e.g. $a_n=\sin n$)

Comment: This seems to imply we wouldn't say "the limit doesn't exist" for $\infty$ or that we wouldn't say "$a_n=\sin n$ diverges". But both are common in a Calculus class/text.

Comment: @MarkS. Yes you are right, I know that since I've encountered also that convention sometimes here on MSE, but I really prefer the way I gave as an answer since in that way we can distinguish between the second and third case which are so different. For that I've used the term "usually".